# sh: nodemon: command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I changed the source of my zsh with `source ~/.zshrc` and all of my npm packages while using the npm run command in package.json have stopped working. I've tried to search for answers online and they say to add the bash source. I don't have bash installed and I don't know where the previous configuration file was located. I've added various lines to export in my `zshrc` file but it has not fixed my packages.

The error I'm receiving

```
sh: nodemon: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
```

This is my .zsrch

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/admin/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/admin/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/admin/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/admin/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'; fi

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/admin/npm/bin
export PATH=$PATH:~/npm
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
```

I don't want to install nodemon globally with `-g` because this is happening to all of my packages. I can't install every last package globally, there's like 500 of them in the package.lock

Comment: You claim to use zsh, but the error message says that `sh` is executing the code, not `zsh`. Aside from this, check your PATH, i.e. verify that the settings you have done are really in effect.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing my node_modules folder and doing an npm install again.